# Pandas: changing years based on an int value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to subtract years from one column based on a number in another column.

This is what i mean:

```
   base_date          amount_years
0  2006-09-01         2
1  2007-04-01         4
```

The result would be:

```
   base_date          amount_years
0  2008-09-01         2
1  20011-04-01        4
```

Is there a way to achieve this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DateOffset`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects) with `apply` and `axis=1` for process per rows:

```
f = lambda x: x['base_date'] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=x['amount_years'])
df['base_date'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
print (df)
   base_date  amount_years
0 2008-09-01             2
1 2011-04-01             4
```

Comment: It appears to give me this error: TypeError: ('must be str, not relativedelta', 'occurred at index 7')

Comment: What is value in index `7`? `print(df.loc[7, 'amount_years'])`?

Comment: Nevermind, worked perfectly after converting the columns to datetime. Thanks again, you helped me two days ago as well :)